# Embedded Excel spreadsheet that is populated by SQL statements using a database

Tags: html, sql, database, excel

I am about to start a project at work and I am leaning in the direction of just creating a webpage to be uploaded to our apache server with an embeded excel document that will be populated by SQL statements so it will be a live stream of data.

What I was wondering before I start the project is if this is a viable route or is there a better way of doing this.

Also to note the only language I am avaiable to use for delevopment is Perl 5.10.1 (Which can include shell commands from bash) and obviously HTML.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need Excel? Data from a database is usually displayed in a web page using, for example, an HTML table. An Excel worksheet cannot easily be displayed on a web page.

Comment: No particular reason as to why I need to use excel I just thought it would be the nicest looking format. However I will look into a html table as I am looking for the simplest soultion.

Comment: Excel is mostly used to hold data or create exports. If it's for an application I recommend building it for the web.